# $rootScope object not available in another controller (but is available in view)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a user authentication  service that creates a `currentUser` object when the user is logged in.  This is available to all views, but I can't seem to get it available to another controller.

I'm trying to use this object in the other controller to publish to my Firebase:

Authentication service snippet:

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', function($firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, FIREBASE_URL) {

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    auth.$onAuth(function(authUser) {
        if(authUser) {
            var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + authUser.uid);
            var user = $firebaseObject(ref);
            $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        } else {
            $rootScope.currentUser = '';
        }
    });
```

Controller trying to access the `currentUser` object:

```
myApp.controller('MyTastingsController',
  function($scope, $firebaseArray, $rootScope, FIREBASE_URL) {

 console.log(currentUser);

  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + 
    $rootScope.currentUser.$id + '/tastings');

  var tastingsInfo = $firebaseArray(ref);

  tastingsInfo.$loaded().then(function(data) {
    $scope.tastings = data;
  }); //make sure tastings data is loaded
```

I noticed the failure initially when it couldn't find the `$id` of `undefined`, so I put the console.log up at the top and `currentUser` returns as undefined there, too.  Any ideas?

The view that uses this controller can properly call currentUser params.

** EDIT: ** I've changed the console.log to be looking for `$rootScope.currentUser` as it should have been, and now I sometimes get the correct info, but not always.  After refreshing or some other action, many times I will get the undefined error.  This strikes me as some sort of timing issue, but I"m not sure how to attack it.

** EDIT 2: ** I added another console.log for tastingsInfo right after I define it using `$firebaseArray` and get the following in the console:

[image: Console.log output for tastingsInfo]

Comment: Are you certain that the `$onAuth` is running before your controller code?

Comment: Chris, that's exactly what I'm wondering.  I'm pretty new to Angular - do you have any suggestions for going about figuring out the answer to that question?

Comment: It's almost certainly not since it's an async request. Any time you contact a server, there is going to be a delay.